# How to set the font size of data label in fviz_pca_var of factoextra

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I submitted a paper to a journal, the journal asked me to set the font size to  7.5, however when I　used the following code, only the axis text changed, the label size remained unchanged,

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(FactoMineR)
    library(factoextra)

    irispca <- PCA(iris,quali.sup = 5)
    fviz_pca_var(irispca)+
   theme(text = element_text(size = 7.5),
         axis.title = element_text(size = 7.5),
         axis.text = element_text(size = 7.5)
         )
```

Any suggestion is appreciated to  tell what code should I used to change the label size?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Getting into `fviz_pca_var` looks like you can just pass a labelsize in the function:

```
irispca <- PCA(iris,quali.sup = 5)
fviz_pca_var(irispca, labelsize = 3, repel = TRUE) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 7.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 7.5),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 7.5))
```

[image]

Comment: great, where did you find this augment? This is not seen in ?fviz_pca_var help page.

Comment: why the labelsize was set to 3 instead of 7.5?

Comment: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/fviz-pca-quick-principal-component-analysis-data-visualization-r-software-and-data-mining

Looks like it only takes integers and 7 looks like 14 font.

Comment: Also be sure to mark the question answered if this is what you needed.

Comment: Many thanks, hope the author of the package add this augment to the help page.

Answer (score 1):

The argument labelsize is passed as an aditional argument to the `fviz()` function. If you then go to the `fviz` help page, the argument is there.

I would rather add a comment to the above answer but I do not have the required reputation so pardon me...